# Return Carousel item "active" to a variable

Tags: jquery, return, carousel

```js
  $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000,
        pause: "hover",
    });
    
    
    $("#nxt").on("click",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    $("#ImVwr").carousel("next")
});    
    $("#prv").on("click",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    $("#ImVwr").carousel("prev");
});
    
    
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++){
  var ff = function(x){
    return function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#ImVwr").carousel(x);

    }
  }
  $("#i0" + i.toString()).on("click",ff(i));
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#hi").click(function(){
    $("#car02").show();
    $("#car01").hide();
  });
  $("#bye").click(function(){
    $("#car01").show();
    $("#car02").hide();
  });

  $("#no").click(function(){
    $("stripb").stop();
  });

});
```

```css
.icons {
  font-size:20px;
  color:#ddd;
  padding: 2px;
  text-shadow:0 -1px 0px rgba(1,1,1,0.4);
}

.drop-shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-radius:5px;
}

.mini-drpshdw {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-radius:3px;
}



img.cla {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

img:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
}

.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.stroke {
 color: #fff;
 -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #000;
/* opacity: 0.5;*/
}
.stroke-transparent {
 -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #000;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
    .big {
    font-size: 30px
}
.carousel {
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    ...
}/*display: none;*/
  .carousel-nab{
  top:0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 60%;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
 /* font-style: italic;*/
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  color:#ddd;
  text-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(1,1,1,0.9);
}

  .carousel-ban {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
 filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  opacity: .7;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#fff

}



.carousel .carousel-ban { visibility: hidden; }
.carousel:hover .carousel-ban { visibility: visible; }
.carousel .carousel-control { visibility: hidden; }
.carousel:hover .carousel-control { visibility: visible; }

.item.next .carousel-ban {
    opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-ban {
  transition: opacity .25s linear ;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s linear ;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s linear ;
}
 .stripa {
  text-align: center;

 }
  .stripb {
  display:none;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

   <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"> 
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
     <link href="//d2c5utp5fpfikz.cloudfront.net/3_1_1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="//d2c5utp5fpfikz.cloudfront.net/3_1_1/css/bootstrap.css.map" rel="stylesheet">
     <script src="//d2c5utp5fpfikz.cloudfront.net/3_1_1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
     </style>

      <title>doubleStrip carousel</title>
<br><br>
   </head>
   <body>
 

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4"></div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
      <button id="hi">show</button>
      <button id="bye">hide</button>
      
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4"></div>
     </div>


      <div class=" row">
        <div class=" col-md-2"></div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div id="contenedor">     

          <div id="ImVwr" class="carousel slide drop-shadow">
             

            <div class=" carousel-inner"> 

              <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600&text=oneCat!" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-ban clearfix visible-lg visible-md">
                  <h4>Title</h4>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.osam laborum dolorum?<p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-nab ">Este es un texto claro</div>
              </div>

              <div class="item ">
                <img  src="http://placehold.it/600&text=twoCat!" alt="">
                <div id="fdon"class="carousel-ban clearfix visible-lg visible-md ">                  
                  <div> <h4 >Title</h4> <p id="fdon2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.osam laborum dolorum?</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-nab ">no debe ser problema</div>
              </div>

              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600&text=threeCat!" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-ban clearfix visible-lg visible-md ">
                  <h4 >Title</h4>
                  <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. similique rerum error!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-nab ">se lee sin inconvenientes</div>
              </div>

              <div class="item ">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600&text=fourCat!" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-ban clearfix visible-lg visible-md ">
                  <h4 >Title</h4>
                  <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. dolorum quod omnis odit deserunt aliquam commodi?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-nab ">Caption clara y comprensible</div>
              </div>

              <div class="item ">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600&text=fiveCat!" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-ban clearfix visible-lg visible-md ">
                  <h4 >Title</h4>
                  <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. dolorum quod omnis odit deserunt aliquam commodi?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-nab ">Tiene un caption visible</div>
              </div>

              <div class="item ">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600&text=sixDog!" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-ban clearfix visible-lg visible-md ">
                  <h4 >Title</h4>
                  <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. dolorum quod omnis odit deserunt aliquam commodi?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-nab ">Leo mi caption con tranquilidad</div>
              </div>
<!-- ........................................................................................................ -->
              <div class="item ">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600&text=sevenDog!" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-ban clearfix visible-lg visible-md">
                  <h4>Title</h4>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.osam laborum dolorum?<p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-nab ">Este es un texto claro</div>
              </div>

              <div class="item ">
                <img  src="http://placehold.it/600&text=eightDog!" alt="">
                <div id="fdon"class="carousel-ban clearfix visible-lg visible-md ">                  
                  <div> <h4 >Title</h4> <p id="fdon2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.osam laborum dolorum?</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-nab ">no debe ser problema</div>
              </div>

              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600&text=nineDog!" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-ban clearfix visible-lg visible-md ">
                  <h4 >Title</h4>
                  <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. similique rerum error!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-nab ">se lee sin inconvenientes</div>
              </div>

              <div class="item ">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600&text=tenDog!" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-ban clearfix visible-lg visible-md ">
                  <h4 >Title</h4>
                  <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. dolorum quod omnis odit deserunt aliquam commodi?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-nab ">Caption clara y comprensible</div>
              </div>

              <div class="item ">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600&text=elevenDog!" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-ban clearfix visible-lg visible-md ">
                  <h4 >Title</h4>
                  <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. dolorum quod omnis odit deserunt aliquam commodi?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-nab ">Tiene un caption visible</div>
              </div>

              <div class="item ">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600&text=twelveDog!" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-ban clearfix visible-lg visible-md ">
                  <h4 >Title</h4>
                  <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. dolorum quod omnis odit deserunt aliquam commodi?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-nab ">Leo mi caption con tranquilidad</div>
              </div>
<!-- ........................................................................................................ -->
            </div>

              <a class="carousel-control left" href="#ImVwr" data-slide="prev">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>

             </a>
              <a class="carousel-control right" href="#ImVwr" data-slide="next">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
             </a>
          </div>
       
        </div> 

        </div> 

        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      </div>
 
<br><br>

      <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-2"></div>

        <div class=" text-center col-md-8 clearfix visible-lg visible-md ">
         
         <div id="car01" class=" stripa">
           <a href="#" id="prv"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left icons mini-drpshdw"></i></a>
           <a href="#" id="i00"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&text=0cat" alt="#" class="img-rounded cla mini-drpshdw "></a>
           <a href="#" id="i01"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&text=1cat" alt="#" class="img-rounded cla mini-drpshdw "></a>
           <a href="#" id="i02"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&text=2cat" alt="#" class="img-rounded cla mini-drpshdw "></a>
           <a href="#" id="i03"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&text=3cat" alt="#" class="img-rounded cla mini-drpshdw "></a>
           <a href="#" id="i04"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&text=4cat" alt="#" class="img-rounded cla mini-drpshdw "></a>
           <a href="#" id="i05"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&text=5cat" alt="#" class="img-rounded cla mini-drpshdw "></a>
           <a href="#" id="nxt"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right icons mini-drpshdw"></i></a>

        </div>  

      </div>

        <div class=" col-md-2"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-2"></div>

        <div class=" text-center col-md-8 clearfix visible-lg visible-md ">
         
          <div id="car02" class=" stripb">         
           <a href="#" id="prv"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left icons mini-drpshdw"></i></a>
           <a href="#" id="i06"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&text=6dog" alt="#" class="img-rounded cla mini-drpshdw "></a>
           <a href="#" id="i07"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&text=7dog" alt="#" class="img-rounded cla mini-drpshdw "></a>
           <a href="#" id="i08"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&text=8dog" alt="#" class="img-rounded cla mini-drpshdw "></a>
           <a href="#" id="i09"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&text=9dog" alt="#" class="img-rounded cla mini-drpshdw "></a>
           <a href="#" id="i010"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&text=10dog" alt="#" class="img-rounded cla mini-drpshdw "></a>
           <a href="#" id="i011"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&text=11dog" alt="#" class="img-rounded cla mini-drpshdw "></a>
           <a href="#" id="nxt"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right icons mini-drpshdw"></i></a>

        </div>  

      </div>

        <div class=" col-md-2"></div>
      </div>


    

   </div> <!-- ndcnt -->

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I made a carousel with 12 elements. I have two strip of thumbnail with 6 elements each one.
The names are id: "#car01" and "#car02".

I'm swapping between thumbnail strips for the first 6 slides to the 6 second with a click button on the top show and hide

```
 $("#first").click(function(){
    $("#car02").show();
    $("#car01").hide();
  });
  $("#second").click(function(){
    $("#car01").show();
    $("#car02").hide();
  });
```

That's work fine, but...

I've put all the images on the same container class "carousel-inner" because that way I can show all the images list. When the slideshow is showing the first slide from part two, the slide number 6 the thumbnail strip should swap from "#car01" to "#car02" 
but I can't really imagine how to do that.

I've tried:

```
  if($("#mycarousel").carousel(6).children('.item').hasClass('active')) {
    $("#car02").show();
    $("#car01").hide();
}
```

doesnt´work

```
  if($("#ImVwr").carousel(6).children('.item')) == (.hasClass.contains('active')) {
$("#car02").show();
$("#car01").hide();
```

}

doesn't work either

I didn't find any clue in the web nor here on stackoverflow.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uncutest/1pqpb1n5/1/)
For more clarification I did [this video capture](http://youtu.be/n8iI_BmK1Q0). First 6 slides Pepe le pew & penelope. Second 6 lides Marc Anthony and Pussyfoot. (on the code snippet I've used just numbers and CAT DOG for each slide group).

Can't auto swap when 1st item from the new list (DOG) is active. ATM I'm looking for a good way for use Carousel.item."active" as a variable.

Comment: can you give us a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I couldn't  make it work on fiddle but you can check the code here

Comment: @CerlinBoss it's working fine on the code snippet pleas help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/1pqpb1n5/3/)

I have assigned an event handler for `slid.bs.carousel` event. The code is mentioned below

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000,
    pause: "hover",
}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var a = $('.carousel-inner .item');
    a.splice(0, 6);
    if (!a.hasClass('active')) $("#bye").trigger('click');
    else $("#hi").trigger('click');
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Cerlin Boss This solve the isuue perfectly. I was unsure about this carousel, because was my first one, but now I can keep developing the rest of the website. Also, I'll contribute to others people  post when I have finished all this.
Did I Mention I Love You?
I do.
Deeply.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In this QA site, when an answer is realized, we do not append &quot;(SOLVED)&quot; to the question title. Instead, we mark a correct answer by clicking on the checkbox to the upper-left of that answer. If you come up with the answer yourself, then post your own answer, give it some time, and if no one has a better answer (your discretion), you can accept your own after a 48-hour wait period.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @Cerlin Boss! I was looking for that but i couldn't find the check mark before you told me!
Aslo I was lurking about how to mark an answer as correct so,your comment  couldn't be better. I apreciate your help very much.
 And it is so much so that,  I am going to raise my rep only for giving you 1 point :D

Answer (score 0):

Cerlin Boss got a solution for you, but you still have a little problem left.

The left and right arrows of car02 are not working, that's because you need to add a next and prev event for each car00, in this case car01 and car02.

You must modify this:

```
$("#nxt").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#ImVwr").carousel("next")
});
$("#prv").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#ImVwr").carousel("prev");
});
```

to this:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
    $("#car0" + i).find("#nxt").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#ImVwr").carousel("next");
    });

    $("#car0" + i).find("#prv").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#ImVwr").carousel("prev");
    });
}
```

And the final code: http://jsfiddle.net/1pqpb1n5/10/

Comment: Indeed @CTCCoco thank you very much I just leave that unsolved because I was focusing on the other tough stuff. This solution pretty much helps me to add a lot more strips THANK YOU very much!!!!
Is very elegant